# getting data from localstorage in ngOnInit in Angular 4 but it reset its value on refresh

Tags: angular, local-storage

I am using **localstorage** to store data in it and retreiving from it in constructor, I want that check varaible **retain** its value on refresh of page and **compare** its value with the 0, after getting **updated value** if `check == 0` then it should go inside that **function**.

I am stuck on it how this can be possible?

```
check=0;

ngOnInit() { 

    if(this.check==0)
    {
        this.list =new Array();
        this.list.push("Purchase a ring for my beautiful wife","get new GALAXY Note 150","Complete kevin's work ASAP","Buy 2 dozen eggs","Get milk on my way to home");
        localStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify(this.list));
        this.check++;
        localStorage.setItem('incre', JSON.stringify(this.check));
    }

    this.check=JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('incre'));
    this.list=JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('list'));
}
```

Comment: Why not do it in the `ngOnInit` method?

Comment: I also try this code in ngOnInit, problem remain same, If this can be done with ngOnInit then it will be ok

Comment: Is any error log display?

Comment: there is no error, the problem is when i reload the page this.check=0 becomes true and it makes new array again

Comment: I have edit and delete operations in my front end view and i want when i delete or edit some of the values, it should display the updated value and should not run this condition again which make new array again and show all the values again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Remove everything from `constructor`.

`public check: number = 0;`

```
ngOnInit() {
this.check = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('incre')) || 0;


if (this.check === 0) {
 // do the rest
}

}
```

Comment: yup :) glad that i could help. please avoid using the `contructor` for any logic  ;) ( even though it didn't cause any issues in this case )

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly then  `this.check=JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('incre'));` should be at the top of your constructor and then you should compare it in if block

Try this

```
check=0;
list = any[];

constructor() { 

 this.check=JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('incre'));    
 if(this.check == undefined || this.check==0)
 {
  this.list =new Array();
  this.list.push("Purchase a ring for my beautiful wife","get new GALAXY Note 150","Complete kevin's work ASAP","Buy 2 dozen eggs","Get milk on my way to home");
  localStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify(this.list));
  this.check++;
  localStorage.setItem('incre', JSON.stringify(this.check));
 }

  this.list=JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('list'));
}
```

Comment: it have issue, when my code is running for the first time it doesn't have anything in localstorage, so for first time it shows nothing, rest is working fine

Comment: no need to check `undefined`, he initiliase it with a `0` value

Answer (score 0):

Move this statement to the beginning of the constructor

```js
constructor() { 
   this.check=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('incre'));
   if(this.check==0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even set initital `0` like dr.nio's  code.

```
public check: number = 0;
ngOnInit() {
  this.check = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('incre'))
  if (!this.check) {}

}
```

Be clear and readability.